# React Js - how to keep bundle.min.js small?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, minify

I'm pretty new to React and javascript dev. I'm used to java build tools, so now using NPM i've got a new landscape of build tools to learn. I am just getting going into my project and I noticed that my minified, uglified bundle is still ~275kb and I'm wondering how this could scale to a large size app. My raw source code itself is only 34kb, but of course I have to pull in all those frameworks and whatnot.

So - how can I keep the size of my app small as my app grows? It's a bit hard for me to follow stuff I read online because many folks seem to be using Grunt, but i'm just using npm start and npm run build on the package below.

Should I be managing my requires() in different ways to prevent duplicate packaging? I'm not sure where to start...

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "someapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "foo",
  "repository": "",
  "main": "js/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "flux": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "keymirror": "~0.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^6.2.0",
    "envify": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.4.3",
    "reactify": "^0.15.2",
    "uglify-js": "~2.4.15",
    "watchify": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d js/app.js",
    "build": "browserify . -t [envify --NODE_ENV production] | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "Some Guy",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "reactify",
      "envify"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "./js"
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to separate the modules, [the handbook has some examples](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#ignoring-and-excluding)

Comment: Do you plan on conditionally adding some scripts to pages or managing multiple browserify bundles?

Comment: I'll definitely check out the handbook, thanks. I'll manage multiple bundles if I have to, but at this point my app is pure static content with Ajax callouts to my rest api. I'd rather not start segregating app bundles by page and begin round-tripping the server. I think the scalable pattern must already be known and I don't need to discover it anew...

Comment: Keep in mind that React 0.14.7 comes in at ~627kb before minification and ~133kb after. Enabling gzip compression when serving your bundle can bring it down to around ~40kb.

Comment: Yeah just a side note you should probably update to a newer version of react. It's quite normal these days for a bundled app to be 100s of kbs minified. Personally I do wonder if react could be less bloated, if you want something leaner take a look at Deku, Preact, Mercury, Riot etc

Comment: I would split out your app and dependencies into two bundles. Then you can manage them easier. Then i would evaluate all your dependencies, do you need the entire dependency? Or could you pull some of it in? Id argue with current ES6 you don't need 80% of what jQuery has to offer for example. The other 20% can easily replicated in not too much code, buts thats digressing.

Comment: Yea I was planning to gzip, just haven't done it yet. I definitely don't need all of jquery unless it's a transitive dependency through react. I'm only using jquery for ajax calls. I'll also upgrade react...the debugging tools have been harassing me about that for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve pretty good results with Webpack. I wrote about this in [Optimizing Webpack Prod Build for React + ES6 Apps](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/optimizing-webpack-production-build-for-react-es6-apps-a637e5692aea#.c05cxxta3)

Here's my Webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProd ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'eval',
  context: path.join(__dirname, './client'),
  entry: {
    jsx: './index.js',
    html: './index.html',
    vendor: ['react']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'react-hot',
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    root: [
      path.resolve('./client')
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv) }
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './client',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

### Two key points to consider:

```
devtool: isProd ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : 'eval',
```

This one will output minimal sourcemaps, and will use external files for that, which is good for your final bundle size.

```
    plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv) }
    })
  ],
```

Uglify - well you probably know what it does. Coupled with the `process.env` setting will weed out quite a bit of dev code from React lib.

`CommonsChunkPlugin` will allow you to bundle libraries (or other chunks per your liking) to separate build files. This is particularly awesome as it allows you to set up different caching patterns for vendor libraries. E.g. you can cache those more aggressively than your business logic files.

Oh, and if you care to see my `package.json` that matches this webpack config:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --hot --inline --progress --colors --port 3000",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

**Edit:** Tree shaking is a shiny new version expected in Webpack 2 (currently in beta). Coupled with the config above, it will be a killer feature that will minify your final bundle significantly.

**Edit 2: Webpack 2** I modified an existing sample app to use Webpack 2 config. It resulted in additional 28% savings. See the project here:[Webpack 2 sample config project](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2)

Comment: This looks really helpful and I'll take me some time to work though it so I'll mark this as the answer and study up. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I just added more info and sample code for webpack 2